# How to change config - NgbTooltipConfig placement on resize

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng bootstrap - NgbTooltipConfig. For desktop/tablet, the config placement should be right. For mobile, I need it on bottom. Config value not reflecting in UI even though I changed in config.

How can I resolve this?

`Code:`

```
windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

constructor(private config: NgbTooltipConfig) {
  this.tooltipPos();
}

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
resize(event): void {
  this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  this.tooltipPos();
}

tooltipPos(): void {
  this.config.placement = this.windowWidth <= 500 ? 'bottom' : 'right';
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to call it on window resize when you know that end user will be using desktop or mobile he is not going to resize at all so you should put `config.placement = this.windowWidth <= 500 ? 'bottom' : 'right'` in constructor instead

Comment: Yep, in real devices this issue won't be there. For client demo purposes, we used to resize my screen & show case myself that my site is responsive, my code is compatible for all devices.